# How do I stop IE11 suggesting sites?

Tags: internet-explorer-11

I downloaded IE 11 the other day on my Windows 7 work desktop as a number of sites I use complained that IE8 was outdated.

It's now picked up an annoying habit - if I type a single letter in the address bar, it tries to guess what sites I want. ServerFault is fine, because I've been there before, but the other sites listed I have never visited and have no interest in doing so.

[image]

Can this be turned off?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Open the **Internet Options** dialog.

   [image]
2. Go to the **Content** tab and click the **Settings** button in the **AutoComplete** section.

   [image]
3. Uncheck **Suggesting URLs** and confirm the dialog.

   [image]

Answer (score 4):

**Edit** OP forgot to define OS at first, so this is for Windows 8 and will not help with Windows 7 :)

I think you need too turn off Enhanced suggestions

```
From the Start screen, tap or click Internet Explorer to open Internet Explorer.

Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, then tap Settings.
(If you're using a mouse, point to the bottom-right corner of the screen, move the mouse pointer up, then click Settings.)

Tap or click Privacy and turn Show enhanced suggestions as you type to Off.
```

[Source and details about Auto Searching as well](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/internet-explorer/get-browsing-suggestions#ie=ie-11)

Comment: Annoyingly, it doesn't seem to be an option under Windows 7 - you can turn off "suggested sites" and "search suggestions" but it still happens.